# jquery's round plugin + border

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, css

I wonder how can i get a rounded corner div in IE with borders?

According to jquery plugin jquery.corner.js the job it would be very simple to achieve!
But, I can't make a rounded corner div "with border" working in internet explorer greater than 5...

The following code serves only for testing purposes.

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>somepage</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="classes/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="classes/jquery.corner.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#teste").corner("round 8px").parent().css('padding', '3px').corner("round 10px");
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.demo{
    height: 34px;
    width: 450px;
    background: blue;
}

</style>

</head>
<body bgcolor="green">

<div id="teste" class="demo">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks, as always.

Comment: I've never used that plugin, but parent of #teste would be body, so you're trying to apply rounded corners to a body after applying it to the div. Not sure what the idea here is. Also take a look at CSS3PIE: http://css3pie.com/

Comment: I'm doing that at the moment, thank's it seems very useful...

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) yet?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you go with a CSS way to do it.

You go here and select the colors for your corner.
http://www.spiffycorners.com/

Once done this will give you the css you need to put and sample code how to use it.
It should work very nicely in all browsers. I used it. No images required.

This is sample styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
.spiffy{display:block}
.spiffy *{
  display:block;
  height:1px;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size:.01em;
  background:#b20000}
.spiffy1{
  margin-left:3px;
  margin-right:3px;
  padding-left:1px;
  padding-right:1px;
  border-left:1px solid #870000;
  border-right:1px solid #870000;
  background:#9f0000}
.spiffy2{
  margin-left:1px;
  margin-right:1px;
  padding-right:1px;
  padding-left:1px;
  border-left:1px solid #6f0000;
  border-right:1px solid #6f0000;
  background:#a30000}
.spiffy3{
  margin-left:1px;
  margin-right:1px;
  border-left:1px solid #a30000;
  border-right:1px solid #a30000;}
.spiffy4{
  border-left:1px solid #870000;
  border-right:1px solid #870000}
.spiffy5{
  border-left:1px solid #9f0000;
  border-right:1px solid #9f0000}
.spiffyfg{
  background:#b20000}
</style>
```

This is how to use it:

```
<div>
  <b class="spiffy">
  <b class="spiffy1"><b></b></b>
  <b class="spiffy2"><b></b></b>
  <b class="spiffy3"></b>
  <b class="spiffy4"></b>
  <b class="spiffy5"></b></b>

  <div class="spiffyfg">
    <!-- content goes here -->
  </div>

  <b class="spiffy">
  <b class="spiffy5"></b>
  <b class="spiffy4"></b>
  <b class="spiffy3"></b>
  <b class="spiffy2"><b></b></b>
  <b class="spiffy1"><b></b></b></b>
</div>
```

Happy styling!!

Comment: Well, I can get the corners with css and jquery's plugin what I cant get it's a border... anyway, thank you very much for you tip.

Comment: PIE is definitely MUCH simpler! Just have to add PIE directory to your 
project and write your css3 code for firefox chrome etc. For IE add in the same css3 rule behavior: url(path_to/PIE.htc) that's it!